# Bootstrap-Vue input shows warning icon on the right side in RTL app

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I use Boostrap-Vue and Vue2. I want to use the `b-form-input`. The component provides `state` which can make the box red in case of invalid input. My application is RTL so I want the red icon to be on the left side of be box but I get:

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="modal-label">HEADER</div>
  <b-form-input
   class="modal-input"
   v-model="dNumber"
   type="text"
   :state="stateDNumber"
   :trim="trimInput"/>
</div>
```

In the CSS I have:

```
div {
  margin: auto 0;
  direction: rtl;
}

input {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

How can I move the icon to the left side?

Answer (score 1):

stating `direction: rtl` would have no effect here, as bootstrap-vue components just use hard coded values for directionality, so no RTL support.

this is not very clean, but you could override the CSS selectors in charge of form controls validation:

```
.form-control.is-invalid,
.form-control.is-valid,
.was-validated .form-control:invalid,
.was-validated .form-control:valid {
    /* overriding hard-coded values, quite dirty. */
    background-position: left calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
}

.form-control.is-invalid,
.was-validated .form-control:invalid {
    /* this one is bluntly copied from the base rule
       in .form-control, which makes it even more dirty! */
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    padding-left: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
}
```

if you want a more robust solution, i would suggest using another library, with better (well, existing) support for bi-directionality.

after a little searching, i found that [**vuetify**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) does what you're after [out of the box](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/bidirectionality/).

Comment: Thanks Eliran. Does Bootstrap-Vue provides a way to pass a custom UI, somehow to override the original UI? I could in that case, implement my own version.

Comment: @vesii, not to my knowledge, it doesn't. and it doesn't seem like there is a clean way to extend it as well.